# How to compare enums in Scala?

Tags: scala, enums

I haven't fond any resource telling me how to compare enums in Scala in DenseVectors:

```
import breeze.linalg._

object StepThresholdConsideration extends Enumeration {
  type StepThresholdConsideration = Value
  val Inclusive, Strict = Value
}

val stepThresholdConsideration = DenseVector(StepThresholdConsideration.Strict, StepThresholdConsideration.Strict, StepThresholdConsideration.Inclusive)
stepThresholdConsideration :== DenseVector.fill(3, StepThresholdConsideration.Strict)
stepThresholdConsideration :== DenseVector.fill(3, StepThresholdConsideration.Inclusive)
```

This does not work. Why?

```
stepThresholdConsideration.map(_ == StepThresholdConsideration.Strict)
stepThresholdConsideration.map(_ == StepThresholdConsideration.Inclusive)
```

on the other hand works.

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: And what "on the other hand works" ?